# Set encoding for process output issue

Tags: c++, qt, windows, windows-console

I want to set encoding for a Windows console process for Russian ouput. In C# the `Process` has a `StandardOutputEncoding` attribute, but in Qt no such functionality exists.

Here is the problem:

[image]

Any suggestion how to accomplish it?

**Update:**

I have tried `QTextStream` `setCodec` function:

```
void Test1::getData(QByteArray data)
{
    QTextStream encodeStream(data);
    encodeStream.setCodec("windows-1251");

    dataTextBrowser->append(encodeStream.readAll());
    emit dataFinished();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: What is the output of the `CHCP` command?

Comment: @lit

I have checked by `GetOEMCP()` function, it returns `866`.

Comment: Use `IBM 866` instead.

Comment: @MichaelO.

Ok. I will try it and reply.

Comment: @MichaelO.

I have tried these functions to set `IBM 866`:
qDebug() << `SetOEMCP("IBM 866")`;
qDebug() << `SetConsoleCP("IBM 866")`;
qDebug() << `SetConsoleOutputCP("IBM 866")`;
qDebug() << `GetOEMCP()`;

I get errors:
C3861: '`SetOEMCP`': identifier not found
C2664: '`BOOL SetConsoleCP(UINT)`': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [8]' to 'UINT'
C2664: '`BOOL SetConsoleOutputCP(UINT)`': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [8]' to 'UINT'

Comment: @Cobra91151 `encodeStream.setCodec("IBM 866");`

Comment: @MichaelO. 

It's working. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't Qt support the console's wide-character API? Using codepages is a legacy nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Michael O**. I have fixed the issue. Also, I included the code here, so others can find the solution.

**Code:**

```
void Test1::getData(QByteArray data)
{
    QTextStream encodeStream(data);
    encodeStream.setCodec("IBM 866");
    dataTextBrowser->append(encodeStream.readAll());
    emit dataFinished();
}
```